# Highcharts, MYSQL and Drilldown

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts, drilldown

I really need to be able to perform a drill down for columns of data. Note there will be 4 columns of data per month.

I have also seen examples of the drill down column on the Highcharts website site. I do understand how it works if the data is hard coded. But this data needs to be pulled from a database.

I can get a basic chart from the following my_data.php file.

```
[{"name":"ONE","data":[1077668]},{"name":"TWO","data":[39657923]}, {"name":"THREE","data":[99428783]},{"name":"FOUR","data":[4431354]}]

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var chart;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.getJSON("my_data.php", function(json) {

                chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        type: 'column',
                        marginRight: 130,
                        marginBottom: 25
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'testing',
                        x: -20 //center
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: '',
                        x: -20
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Amount'
                        },
                        plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 1,
                            color: '#808080'
                        }]
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            formatter: function() {
                                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                                    this.x +': '+ this.y;
                            }

                        },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        x: -10,
                        y: 100,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    },
                    series: json
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am really confused on where in this type of chart i would put the drilldown call? I do know it should be something like the follow. I also think there will be multiple if/else statement for the different drilldowns.

```
click: function() {
    var drilldown = this.drilldown;
    if (drilldown) { // drill down
        var chart = this.series.chart;
        $.getJSON(...., function(data){
            chart.setTitle({
                text: data.name
            });
            setChart(data.name, data.categories, data.data, data.color, data.level);
        });
    } else { // restore
        setChart(name, categories, data, null, level);    
    }
}
```

If I am using the wrong chart data please let me know. I can use something like this but I am having issues with producing the chart with intial data from the database. because I would have the same issue on where to set the drillname (like level 0, level 1 and so on)

```
var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
categories = ['MSIE', 'Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'Opera'],
name = 'Browser brands',
data = [{
    y: 55.11,
    color: colors[0],
    drilldown: {
        name: 'MSIE versions',
        categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
        data: [10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81],
        color: colors[0]
    }
}, {
    y: 21.63,
    color: colors[1],
    drilldown: {
        name: 'Firefox versions',
        categories: ['Firefox 2.0', 'Firefox 3.0', 'Firefox 3.5', 'Firefox 3.6', 'Firefox 4.0'],
        data: [0.20, 0.83, 1.58, 13.12, 5.43],
        color: colors[1]
    }
}, {
```

Comment: I don't know if this can be related, but you have twice in a row the line `formatter: function() {`

Answer (score 0):

You need to get data from php as JSON un form which is used in drilldown.

Solution of preparing data from php is available here: http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing

Comment: ok thank you for the information. but looking at the first section of code. Where would the drilldown section be insterted? note that after the first drilldown there would be another drilldown after that further detailing the information being presented

Comment: Should be added as in static drilldown example without dynamic data. JSON should look like in both examples. So you need to put your drilldown json in series -> data as in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-drilldown/